# Flink schema evolution for a POJO embedded in another POJO

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a POJO class (field names anonymized) below. I use lombok tags to meet the Flink POJO requirements, and have verified that it is a valid Flink POJO with `PojoTestUtils.assertSerializedAsPojoWithoutKryo()`

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class EmbeddedPojoClass {
  int field1;
  int field2;
  int field3;
  double field4;
  double field5;
}
```

This class is then stored in another POJO class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@TypeInfo(PojoClassTypeInformationFactory.class)
public class PojoClass {
  SortedMap<Instant, EmbeddedPojoClass> timeSeries,
  Instant minTimestamp,
  Instant maxTimestamp,
  long intervalMillis
}
```

which is registered as a Flink POJO using a custom `TypeInformationFactory`

```
public class PojoClassTypeInformationFactory
    extends TypeInfoFactory<PojoClass> {
  @Override
  public TypeInformation<PojoClass> createTypeInfo(
      Type t, Map<String, TypeInformation<?>> genericParameters) {
    return Types.POJO(
        PojoClass.class,
        new HashMap<>() {
          {
            put(
                "timeSeries",
                new SortedMapTypeInfo<>(
                    Types.INSTANT.getTypeClass(),
                    EmbeddedPojoClass.class));
            put("minTimestamp", Types.INSTANT);
            put("maxTimestamp", Types.INSTANT);
            put("intervalMillis", Types.LONG);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Like `EmbeddedPojoClass`, I've verified this is a valid POJO with `PojoTestUtils.assertSerializedAsPojoWithoutKryo()` This `PojoClass` is stored in Flink state in one of my operators.

I would now like to add 2 more `Instant` fields to `EmbeddedPojoClass`. So I'd like to change it to:

```
public class EmbeddedPojoClass {
  int field1;
  int field2;
  int field3;
  double field4;
  double field5;

  // New fields
  Instant time1;
  Instant time2;
}
```

After rolling out this change, I get this error when I load back Flink state upon restart:

```
2023-11-21 18:47:57
java.time.DateTimeException: Instant exceeds minimum or maximum instant
    at java.base/java.time.Instant.create(Instant.java:411)
    at java.base/java.time.Instant.ofEpochSecond(Instant.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.InstantSerializer.deserialize(InstantSerializer.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.InstantSerializer.deserialize(InstantSerializer.java:31)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.AbstractMapSerializer.deserialize(AbstractMapSerializer.java:141)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.AbstractMapSerializer.deserialize(AbstractMapSerializer.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer.deserialize(PojoSerializer.java:411)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBValueState.value(RocksDBValueState.java:89)
```

Judging by the stack trace, I see that the `PojoSerializer` is being invoked, but I'm confused why the new fields would be backwards incompatible. Am I missing something here?

I'm using Flink 1.17.1 with RocksDB state backend.

I've validated that the existing Java classes I use in my Flink job are recognized as POJO. I thought adding new fields is supported by POJO schema evolution rules, and don't know why the state checkpoint fails to load with the new fields added.